# How can we show this estimate for the convolution of two probability measures?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, convolution, levy-processes, infinite-divisibility

Let $(\delta_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ be nonincreasing with $\delta_k\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$ and $(\varepsilon_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\varepsilon_k<1/2$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\varepsilon_k/\delta_k\le1/2$.

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be sequences of probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $K_k\subseteq E$ be compact with $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}(\mu_n\ast\nu_n)(K^c_k)<\varepsilon_k\tag1,$$ where $\mu_n\ast\nu_n$ denotes the convolution, for $k\in\mathbb N$.

Now let $$B_n:=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\left\{x\in E:\mu_n(K_k-x)>1-\delta_k\right\}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

> Why does it follow that $\nu_n(B_n)\ge1/2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

We may clearly write $$(\mu_n\ast\nu_n)(K_k)=\int\nu_n({\rm d}y)\mu_n(K_k-y)\ge\int_{B_n}\nu_n({\rm d}y)\mu_n(K_k-y)\ge(1-\delta_k)\nu_n(B_n)\tag2,$$ but that doesn't help, since $(1)$ only yields an inequality in the same direction: $$(\mu_n\ast\nu_n)(K_k)\ge1-\varepsilon_k\tag3.$$

### **EDIT**:

I still wasn't able to figure it out, but it somehow must follow from $$\mu_n(K_k-y)<\delta_k\Leftrightarrow\frac1{\delta_k}<\frac1{\mu_n(K_k-x)}\Leftrightarrow\frac{\varepsilon_k}{\delta_k}<\frac{\varepsilon_k}{\mu_n(K_k-x)}<\frac{(\mu_n\ast\nu_n)(K_k)}{\mu_n(K_k-x)}\tag4,$$ which holds for all $x\in B_n$, and $$\nu_n(B_n)=\int_{B_n}\nu_n({\rm d}x)\frac{\mu_n(K_k-x)}{\mu_n(K_k-x)}\ge\frac1{\delta_k}\int_{B_n}\nu_n({\rm d}x)\mu_n(K_k-x)\tag5.$$ The right-hand side is equal to $$\underbrace{(\mu_n\ast\nu_n)(K_k)}_{\ge\:1-\varepsilon_k}-\underbrace{\int_{B_n}\nu_n({\rm d}x)\mu_n(K_k-x)}_{\le\:1}\ge-\varepsilon_k\tag6,$$ but that's clearly useless, since it trivially holds $\nu_n(B_n)\ge0>-\varepsilon_k/\delta_k$ ...

---

*Remark*: I've asked [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3962424/47771) before, but didn't receive an answer; even with a bounty. (The question on MSE will be deleted after the bounty grace period has ended.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\de\delta$Let $\mu:=\mu_n$, $\nu:=\nu_n$, $B:=B_n$,
$$C_k:=\{x\in E:\mu(K_k-x)>1-\de_k\},$$
so that
$$B=\bigcap_k C_k.$$
We have
$$1-\ep_k<(\mu*\nu)(K_k)=\int\mu(K_k-x)\nu(dx) \\
=\int_{C_k}\mu(K_k-x)\nu(dx)+\int_{C_k^c}\mu(K_k-x)\nu(dx) \\
\le\nu(C_k)+(1-\de_k)\nu(C_k^c)=1-\de_k+\de_k\nu(C_k),$$
whence
$$\nu(C_k)\ge1-\ep_k/\de_k.$$
Thus,
$$\nu(B)\ge1-\sum_k\ep_k/\de_k\ge1/2,$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) If I'm not mistaken, the assumption $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\varepsilon_k<1/2$ is unnecessary, since we don't need to use it. (b) As you may guess, the desired conclusion is that the set $B$ is nonempty (since $\nu(B)>0$). Your proof works perfectly fine even when we relax the assumptions and only assume that $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are sequences of finite nonnegative Radon measures which are (uniformly) bounded in total variation norm. The result then still is $\nu(B^c)\le\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac{\varepsilon_k}{\delta_k}$.

Comment: If we now assume that $\alpha:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\nu_n(E)>0$ and we choose $(\varepsilon_k)_{k\in\mathbb N},(\delta_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac{\varepsilon_k}{\delta_k}<c$, we should still be able to conclude $\nu(B)\ge c-\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac{\varepsilon_k}{\delta_k}>0$. It would be great if you could tell me whether you agree or I am missing something.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : The assumption $\sum_k\varepsilon_k<1/2$ was indeed not used or needed. I think you will have to modify the definition of $B_n$ if $\mu_n$ is no longer a probability measure. Otherwise, I think you can indeed similarly get the corresponding result for any measures $\mu_n,\nu_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, we should only need to replace $\mu_n(K_k-x)>1-\delta_k$ by $\mu_n(K_k-x)>\mu_n(E)-\delta_k$. But you wrote for *any* measure $\mu_n,\nu_n$. So, don't you think we need the condition on $\alpha$ to ensure $\nu_n(B_n)>0$ for all $n$ at the end?

Comment: Of course, if you want $\nu_n(B_n)>0$, then you need to require that $\nu_n(E)>0$.